# Non-exhaustive patterns in function haskell

Tags: haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

I think I am missing the case where there's a one element list but I can't find a way to write it can someone help me?

```
getBoard :: [String] -> [String]
getBoard (h:t) | isLOL h = h: getBoard (t)
               | otherwise = []


isLOL :: String -> Bool
isLOL [ ] = True
isLOL (h:t) | h>='a' && h<='z' || h >='A' && h<='Z' = isLOL t
            | otherwise = False
```

Comment: How about `getBoard []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getBoard [] = []
```

is the line you want. Like this:

```
getBoard :: [String] -> [String]
getBoard [] = []
getBoard (h:t) | isLOL h = h: getBoard (t)
               | otherwise = []


isLOL :: String -> Bool
isLOL [] = True
isLOL (h:t) | h>='a' && h<='z' || h >='A' && h<='Z' = isLOL t
            | otherwise = False
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your definition of `getBoard`, the problem is that the guards (the stuff after the `|`) are checked after the pattern (`h:t` in your case) are matched. So if the argument to `getBoard` doesn't match `h:t` (i.e. is `[]`), then the two branches (including the `otherwise` branch) are not checked. The solution to this is to add a match on `[]`:

```
getBoard (h:t) | isLOL h = h : getBoard t
               | otherwise = []
getBoard [] = []
```

However, matches with failing guards fall through, so you can write that as

```
getBoard (h:t) | isLOL h = h : getBoard t
getBoard _               = []
```

Now, as for how to write this function in a better way, using recursion schemes from the Prelude:

`isLOL` can be rewritten as

```
isLOL = all $ \h -> 'a' <= h && h <= 'z' || 'A' <= h && h<= 'Z'
```

and `getBoard` can be rewritten similarly, noting that it will always return the original list if every character `isLOL`, and the empty list otherwise:

```
getBoard cs | all isLOL cs = cs
            | otherwise = []
```